# Webcam not recognized in Flash app

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, webcam

I have problems in webcam recognition on my Flash app (written in Actionscript 3).

I get webcam source using:

```
Camera.getCamera();
```

but on some PC it doesn't work. 
In particular, some webcam gets LED on but getCamera() still returns false.
How is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
package {
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.media.Camera;
import flash.media.Video;

public class CameraController extends Sprite {
    private var cam:Camera = Camera.getCamera();
    private var vid:Video = new Video(); 

    public function CameraController() {
        connectCamera();
    }


    private function connectCamera():void {
        vid.attachCamera(cam); 
        addChild(vid);
    }
}
}
```

You can read more about using camera here: 
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000867.html